# What's the simplest way of adding state to CLR's DynamicMethod?

Tags: .net, clr, code-generation, dynamicmethod, dynamic-method

I'm doing a little code generation with DynamicMethod and I have a problem that would be handily solved by adding a little state, like a field. Unfortunately, I can't push this state into one of the method's parameters, so I basically need to close over a local like this little lambda:

```
var i = 0;
return new Func<int>(() => i++);
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can't do that, at least not directly. `DynamicMethod` lets you create a single CLR method and nothing else. C# methods don't have that limitation, they are free to create closure types and fields in them and whatever else they need.

To achieve what you want, you could use [`TypeBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) to dynamically build a full type with a method and a field.

But a simpler option would be to create the method with the state as a parameter and then use a closure (or, alternatively, a normal object) to capture the state. Something like:

```
Action<TData> CaptureState<TState, TData>(
    Action<TState, TData> originalAction, TState initialState)
{
    var state = initialState;
    return data => originalAction(state, data);
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
Action<State, string> generated = …;
Action<string> captured = CaptureState(generated, new State());
captured("data1");
captured("data2");
```

If your method needs to change the value of the state (and not just modify some properties on it), then you would need to use `ref` parameter for the state, but the principle works the same (it would also mean you would need to use custom delegate type).

Comment: +1 The `Expression` API does just that when you reference an object from a tree.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the creation of new types and assemblies, but perhaps it's not avoidable. I do have a technique that abuses generics to allocate state for a DynamicMethod. Basically just generate a new nested generic type and reference a static variable: http://sasa.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/sasa/sasa/file/41094f47bd3d/Sasa/TypeIndexed.cs